# jQuery call to a MVC async method to load a view's dropdown list. List data not appearing. Can't find jQuery $

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a jQuery function in a view to pass back a list so that I can load a drop down with the list.

I'm not getting any thing in the drop down.

I see in the Source tab that I have an Uncaught ReferenceError: $ not defined.

[image]

---

Not sure why it cannot find the jQuery reference.

I have the jQuery bundle defined in the BundleConfig.cs file.

[image]

The files are in the Script folder:

[image]

I reference the bundles in the _Layout.cshtml:

[image]

I reference the bundles in the _LayoutUser.cshtml:

[image]

I call in the _LayoutUser.cshtml into the view where the drop down and jQuery is defined.

[image]

Comment: You seem a little confused about the purpose of async/await in your C# code, and the client/server relationship. Changing it to a sync method won't change anything to do with your problem. I'd suggest checking the response of the call in the network tab of dev tools to get an error message you can start debugging from

Comment: Rory..yeah I may be. I just new it works with the non-sync version but I guess that led me  to make incorrect conclusions. LOL. Anyway, I looked at the Network tab and found no entries. I looked at the Source tab and there is an error. It cannot find the $ of the jQuery. I will post that and reword this issue. Initially, without knowing that error, I had looked to make sure I had all the  bundles for jQuery thinking it was not executing, I do have them so I did not think it would be that issue. I'm wrong somewhere and not sure why I get that jQuery error.

Comment: I had to add @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") to that specific view. I thought putting them in the _LayoutUser.cshtml  which is then brought in to this specific view was all it took. Looks like they have to be included in every view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") to that specific view. I thought putting them in the _LayoutUser.cshtml which is then brought in to this specific view was all it took. Looks like they have to be included in every view.